# How to find linearly dependent eigenvectors of non-diagonalizable matrix (with exceptions)?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, tensors, eigenvalues

Here is the code to produce a $9\times9$ matrix:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
n = 3; L = 2; 
f[r_] := k /. r; 
g[r_] := \[Lambda] /. r; 
kmoment[i_] := f /@ Solve[Sin[(L + 1)*k] - Sin[L*k]/exceptional[[i]]^(n/2) == 0 && Re[k] != 0 && 
      Pi > Re[k] > 0, k]; 
quasi[\[Lambda]_, k_] := (1 + \[Lambda]^n + 2*\[Lambda]^(n/2)*Cos[k])^(1/n); 
quasienergy[j_] := Table[quasi[exceptional[[j]], kmoment[j][[i]]], {i, 1, Length[kmoment[j]]}]; 
sol = N[f /@ Solve[Sin[(2*L + 1)*k] - (2*L + 1)*Sin[k] == 0 && Pi > Re[k] > 0 && Pi > Im[k] > 0, k, 
      Complexes]]; 
lam = Flatten[Table[Solve[\[Lambda]^n == (-(Sin[(L + 1)*sol[[i]]]/Sin[L*sol[[i]]]))^2], {i, Length[sol]}]]; 
exceptional = g /@ lam
\[Omega] = Exp[2*Pi*(I/n)]; 
CircleTimes = KroneckerProduct; 
Z = DiagonalMatrix[{1, \[Omega], \[Omega]^2}]; 
id = IdentityMatrix[n]; 
X = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0}}; 
Z1 = Z \[CircleTimes] id; 
Z2 = id \[CircleTimes] Z; 
X1 = X \[CircleTimes] id; 
X2 = id \[CircleTimes] X; 
H[\[Lambda]_] := (-\[Lambda])*(ConjugateTranspose[Z1]*Z2) - (X1 + X2); MatrixForm[H[\[Lambda]]]
ei2 = Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[H[exceptional[[2]]]], 10^(-7)]]; MatrixForm[ei2]
ei3 = Sort[Chop[Eigenvalues[H[exceptional[[3]]]], 10^(-7)]]; MatrixForm[ei3]
MatrixForm[Chop[Transpose[Eigenvectors[H[exceptional[[1]]]]]]]
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[H[exceptional[[1]]]]
Det[Eigenvectors[H[exceptional[[1]]]]]
{s, j} = JordanDecomposition[H[exceptional[[1]]]]; MatrixForm[Chop[j, 10^(-7)]]
Det[s]
```

I know that at these particular values, the matrix is not diagonalizable:

```
exceptional = {-1.5874010519681996, 0.7937005259840997 - 1.3747296369986026*I, 0.7937005259840998 + 1.3747296369986026*I}
```

For example:

```
DiagonalizableMatrixQ[H[exceptional[[1]]]]
```

will return the result "False", and its corresponding eigenvector matrix has a vanishing determinant as expected:

```
Det[Eigenvectors[H[exceptional[[1]]]]]
```

Is it possible to write a code to find which eigenvectors are linearly dependent? Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I get from `DiagonalizableMatrixQ[H[exceptional[[1]]]]`  `True`. And From `Det[Eigenvectors[H[exceptional[[1]]]]]`  `0.0380631 + 0.00254609 I`. MMA version 14.0

Comment: I have edited it to include all the code. I quit kernel and I got the same result I had before. MMA version 13.3

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but dependencies among eigenvectors would happen within sets that have the same (to close approximation) eigenvalues.

Comment: Also there seem to be more exceptional valuies. Check `NSolveValues[
 Discriminant[CharacteristicPolynomial[H[lambda], t], t] == 0, lambda]`. Some might be approximate duplicates though.

Comment: Thanks. In this case, there are only 3 exceptional values (I took the question out of the physical contexts). I will check the rank of the eigenvector matrix.